# Array para resolver puzzle de frase escondida

Tags: java, c#, portugol

" Você tem dois arrays

```
letras   = ["m", "D", " ", "e", " ", "G", "v", "e", "i", "e", " ", "r", "S", "G", "D", "u"];

caminho  = [ 12, 7, 11, 9, 8, 4, 15, 0, 2, 13, 14, 5, 10, 1, 3, 6];
```

Há uma frase escondida que você tem que descobrir, mas não apenas isso!
você deve escrever a função (em qualquer linguagem de programação) que resolva o problema. "

---

Boa tarde, preciso resolver esse problema e gostaria de sugestões, pois estou no segundo período de BSI e não estou compreendendo o que é o "caminho" do array.

Comment: Caminho significa que você deve acessar elementos do array `letras` pelo índice dado pelos elemento no array `caminho`. E.g:  `letras[12]`, `letras[7]`, `letras[11]`, etc. O que você tentou até agora? (Poste o seu código).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer usando C# seria dessa forma:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //Array de caracteres utilizadas para montar a frase
        var letras = new string[] { "m", "D", " ", "e", " ", "G", "v", "e", "i", "e", " ", "r", "S", "G", "D", "u" };
        //Array de index referente ao array de letras para montar a fras
            var caminho = new int[] { 12, 7, 11, 9, 8, 4, 15, 0, 2, 13, 14, 5, 10, 1, 3, 6 };
            //A variável para acumular os caracteres
            var frase = string.Empty;
            //Para cada index no array de indexes, adiciona o carácter na variável para armazenar a frase
            foreach(var index in caminho)
            {
                frase += letras[index];
            }
            //Escreve a frase no console.
            Console.WriteLine("Frase: " + frase);
    }
}
```

Pode visualizar o resultado no [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PNbmU6)